# How to write a string to numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy

I have two attributes age (float) and name (string) that belongs to a person. I want to write them to csv file, hence, I used numpy to store data, then write it to csv.

```
import numpy as np
import random
age_name = np.empty((2, 10))
print (age_name.shape)
for i in range (10):
    age = random.randint(0,100)
    name =  'ABC'
    age_name[0,i]=age
    age_name[1,i]=name
print (age_name)
```

I got the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 9, in 
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ABC'

It may be a not a good option because the data has both string and float number, could you suggest to me a good way that can easy to store to csv file?

Comment: you can pass `dtype = object` to `np.empty` or use a custom data-type if efficiency matters.

Comment: `age_name = np.empty((2, 10), dtype=str)` and print (age_name) will be `[['8' '2' '6' '4' '9' '9' '7' '6' '2' '4']
 ['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']]`

Comment: Sorry. I was misundersand.

Comment: @trailing_whitespace It worked. Thanks. But the solution cannot write to csv file. Let try it np.savetxt("age_name.csv", age_name, delimiter=",")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of numpy had chararrays and numarrays, but now you just pass a dtype to tell numpy that the array needs to contain more than just numbers.  Using dtype=str will only take one string per element, so you will get "a" "a" "a"..., instead of the whole string "abc".  To get that, you pass `object` as the dtype.

```
import numpy as np
import random
age_name = np.zeros((2, 10), dtype=object)
print (age_name)
for i in range (10):
    age = random.randint(0,100)
    name =  'ABC'
    age_name[0,i]=age
    age_name[1,i]=name
print (age_name)

>>>[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
>>> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>>[[24 67 72 59 44 4 71 16 17 82]
>>> ['ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC' 'ABC']]
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But the solution cannot write to csv file. Let try it  `np.savetxt("age_name.csv", age_name, delimiter=",")`

Comment: @John You have to include the fact that it is a string in the format to use numpy.savetxt.  Try: `np.savetxt("age_name.csv", age_name, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")`

Answer (score 0):

For heterogenous data (with differently typed columns, some of which contain `str`/`object` data) use `pandas.DataFrame`s.

For data of "mixed types" where (legitimate) strings can be found *within each/some column(s)* interspersed with numeric values, use python `dict`s.

Only for uniform data (typically numeric) use `numpy.ndarray`s.